# Hi i want to disable (delete) these permissions from my app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi i want to disable (delete) these permissions from my app

WRITE EXTERNAL STORAGE

```
    READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

    WAKE_LOCK
```

and disable using camera and taking photos
the source code of users permissions in my app, I am using android studio.

that is the source how will be the new ??

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bpositive"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0.3" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> <!-- Permissions required for GCM -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.bpositive.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.bpositive.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <application
        android:name="sample.bpositive.sparkleappz.app.BPlus"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="sample.bpositive.sparkleappz.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="sparkleappz.com/"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="sparkleappz.com/"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="sample.bpositive.sparkleappz.activities.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="sample.bpositive.sparkleappz.activities.ResetPasswordActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="sample.bpositive.sparkleappz.activities.DonateActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <service android:name="sample.bpositive.sparkleappz.MyFirebaseMessagingService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="sample.bpositive.sparkleappz.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" /> <!-- Include the AdActivity and InAppPurchaseActivity configChanges and themes. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.IAPTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.appinvite.PreviewActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppInvite.Preview" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.appinvite.ACTION_PREVIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <!--
 FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.bpositive" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!--
 Internal (not exported) receiver used by the app to start its own exported services
             without risk of being spoofed.
        -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
            android:exported="false" />
        <!--
 FirebaseInstanceIdService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:authorities="com.bpositive.firebaseinitprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="100" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Hi i want to disable (delete) these permissions from my app

WRITE EXTERNAL STORAGE

```
    READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

    WAKE_LOCK
```

and disable using camera and taking photos
the source code of users permissions in my app, I am using android studio.

that is the source how will be the new ??

Comment: just remove the specific line

Comment: Why you want to delete this permission??? and If you dont want that permission dont add it in to manifest file

Comment: JUST TRY TO  RESKIN IT   .disable using camera and taking photos which lines i delete ?

Comment: you should go through basic android tutorials first, also you may still face some errors if you have not removed the codes that used those permissions @juba

Answer (score 2):

There is a line in your file that reads

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and one that reads

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

If you delete them and rerun gradle, your project will now no longer have those permissions.

Comment: and disable using camera and taking photos the source code of users permissions in my app,

Answer (score 0):

Remove this lines from your

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

to remove the permissions

Comment: and disable using camera and taking photos the source code of users permissions in my app

Answer (score 0):

You can't just remove permissions and hope your app to work if permissions are essential for that to work or triggered on user interaction like touching camera button to invoke camera and require camera permissions. If that app requires that permissions you remove those permission you will get errors especially that apps targets for above Android 6.0 with `android:targetSdkVersion="25"`.

If you are hoping to publish that app with JUST RESKIN you will get a strike because publishing a spam app. You should do some modification on that app to be considered as modified work. You should also check licanse for license whether you are allowed to do or not.